# How to make video on media player classic more vivid?

Tags: video, media-player-classic

Is there way to make video played on media player classic more vivid, like PowerDVD or Sony LCD TV ?

Comment: "more vivid" like what? What do PowerDVD or the TV offer exactly?

Comment: How would you define more vivid?  Seems a very subjective thing.  I use both classic MP and PowerDVD and notice no differences on my system.

Comment: My gut feeling is "Use VLC Player" or "Adjust TV settings"

Comment: I just figured out that Sony has X-Reality PRO Engine to make video very crisp and vivid : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Dl0c87el9M Any PC software can do thing like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the newer versions of it, switch to VRM-9 (windowed) Render mode In View/options, playback/output/direct show. Then go into View/Options , at the bottom select Miscellaneous , Then you can tweak the saturation brightness contrast and hue.  These controls are in the later versions of MPC and MPC HomeCinema.

Comment: I just figured out that Sony has X-Reality PRO Engine to make video very crisp and vivid : youtube.com/watch?v=2Dl0c87el9M Any PC software can do thing like that ?